# using dicts for code and variables

Tags: python, dictionary, scope, switch-statement

I have the following code that finally works!   But as a Python newb, I'd like to see if there is a better way to do it.  In particular, as part of a project in monte carlo chemical kinetics, the loop at the bottom has to be really really fast.  Should this be fast?  Is there a better (more pythonic) way to do this than bundling everything up in dictionaries?  These dictionaries could have as many as hundreds of entries.  Thanks!

```
def split(pops,src, dst): pops[src] -= 1; pops[dst] += 2
def join(pops,src, dst) : pops[src] -= 1; pops[dst] += 2
def jump(pops,src, dst) : pops[src] -= 1; pops[dst] += 2

j1, j2, s1, s2, m1, m2, d1, d2 = .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1

pops = {'mon1':1000,    # initial population of monomers in regime 1
        'dim1':1000,    #        "              dimers   "
        'mon2':1000,    # etc.
        'dim2':1000}

trns = {'j1':(j1, join, 'mon1', 'dim1'),  # j1=prob of 2 monomers joining to form a dimer
        'j2':(j2, join, 'mon2', 'dim2'),  
        's1':(s1, split,'dim1', 'mon1'),
        's2':(s2, split,'dim2', 'mon2'),
        'm1':(m1, jump ,'mon1', 'mon2'),
        'm2':(m2, jump ,'mon2', 'mon1'),
        'd1':(d1, jump ,'dim1', 'dim2'),
        'd2':(d2, jump ,'dim2', 'dim1')}    

while True: 
    event = 's1' # this would be derived from rand(), called many times

    action  = trns[event][1]   # either join, split or jump
    source  = trns[event][2]   # source species
    dest    = trns[event][3]   # destination species

    action(pops, source, dest) # make the function call to update populations
    break

print pops
```

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to write anything faster than `dict`. How do I know? Because it would already have been written.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to do Monte Carlo simulations using a library that has already been optimized to do them efficiently, allowing you do work more directly in your problem domain rather than in the python code writing domain. See, for example, Monte Carlo in the python library scipy. http://www.scipy.org/topical-software.html

Comment: Thanks Fred.  The Monte Carlo code on that website seems more for doing _a posteriori_ calculations on existing datasets.  I've done a lot of looking for packaged stuff, and not found anything suitable.  So Python here I come!